# golangci-lint not creating report file

Tags: go

This is the only .golangci.yaml file in my working-dir:

```
run:
  modules-download-mode: readonly
  tests: false

output:
  formats:
    - format: checkstyle
      path: report.xml

linters:
  disable-all: true
  enable:
  - misspell
 
issues:
  exclude-use-default: false
  max-issues-per-linter: 0
  max-same-issues: 0
```

When I run golangci-lint run ,it gives me:

```
main.go:11:20: `explicity` is a misspelling of `explicitly` (misspell)
    // URL to send explicity GET request to
```

I want to include this in a report.xml.I looked at the documentation and it was suggested to do like this but it's not creating report file for me? Do you know why the config file is not generating the report file

Comment: it works for me, its creating the reportfile.xml.
I just copy/pasted your yaml file and upgraded golangci-lint to the latest version: `golangci-lint has version v1.57.1 built with go1.21.3`

Comment: Very weird.Its not working for me .I am using it on macos in vscode editor and my golangci-lint version is 1.56.2 built with go1.22.0.I will try updating it and check

Comment: Thanks a lot.It seems it didn't work with my version but it works with the 1.57.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `golangci-lint`'s help?

```
$ golangci-lint run --help
Run the linters

Usage:
  golangci-lint run [flags]

Flags:
<snip reason="brevity">
      --out-format string              Formats of output: colored-line-number|line-number|json|tab|checkstyle|code-climate|html|junit-xml|github-actions|teamcity (default "colored-line-number")
</snip>
```

And then choosing the appropriate output, assuming `checkstyle`
in your case?

```
$ golangci-lint run --out-format checkstyle
```

Now, this prints the result out on [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), so you have to redirect the output:

```
$ golangci-lint --out-format checkstyle > report.xml
```

Alternatively, you can use the `--out-format` flag like this:

```
$ golangci-lint run --out-format checkstyle:report.xml
```

Further details can be found in [the part of `golangci-lint`s documentation dealing with output formats](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/#output-configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Do you know why the configuration file is not generating the report file even though I have included the configs from the documentation.I don't want to use the command line arguments because it will override the config file if I am not wrong.

Comment: @needhelp Cannot reproduce your error. Works flawless with me with `golangci-lint has version 1.57.1 built with go1.22.1 from cd890db2 on 2024-03-20T16:34:34Z`.